# Posting and retriving data from an api in javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I want to post to an API in javascript and after posting page should redirect to another page and get the data from another API, can anyone help with the code. I will be using an html form to post data into an api

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

The Submit button of the form should trigger a function that posts the data to an API. This is a clear video on how to work with data and APIs in javaScript: https://youtu.be/Kw5tC5nQMRY

This is how to call a function when the form is submitted: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Then you would redirect the user to a new page, where you can have code that will get data from another API. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp